# Minting dapp does not Connecting to metamask app on mobile?

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask

```
// constants
import Web3EthContract from "web3-eth-contract";
import Web3 from "web3";
// log
import { fetchData } from "../data/dataActions";

const connectRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: "CONNECTION_REQUEST",
  };
};

const connectSuccess = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: "CONNECTION_SUCCESS",
    payload: payload,
  };
};

const connectFailed = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: "CONNECTION_FAILED",
    payload: payload,
  };
};

const updateAccountRequest = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: "UPDATE_ACCOUNT",
    payload: payload,
  };
};

export const connect = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(connectRequest());
    const abiResponse = await fetch("/config/abi.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
    const abi = await abiResponse.json();
    const configResponse = await fetch("/config/config.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
    const CONFIG = await configResponse.json();
    const { ethereum } = window;
    const metamaskIsInstalled = ethereum && ethereum.isMetaMask;
    if (metamaskIsInstalled) {
      Web3EthContract.setProvider(ethereum);
      let web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
      try {
        const accounts = await ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
        });
        const networkId = await ethereum.request({
          method: "net_version",
        });
        if (networkId == CONFIG.NETWORK.ID) {
          const SmartContractObj = new Web3EthContract(
            abi,
            CONFIG.CONTRACT_ADDRESS
          );
          dispatch(
            connectSuccess({
              account: accounts[0],
              smartContract: SmartContractObj,
              web3: web3,
            })
          );
          // Add listeners start
          ethereum.on("accountsChanged", (accounts) => {
            dispatch(updateAccount(accounts[0]));
          });
          ethereum.on("chainChanged", () => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
          // Add listeners end
        } else {
          dispatch(connectFailed(`Change network to ${CONFIG.NETWORK.NAME}.`));
        }
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch(connectFailed("Something went wrong."));
      }
    } else {
      dispatch(connectFailed("Install Metamask."));
    }
  };
};

export const updateAccount = (account) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(updateAccountRequest({ account: account }));
    dispatch(fetchData(account));
  };
};
```

Metamask extension is working fine in desktop but the issue is it not working on Mobile, it is not openning the metamask app, we dont know now how to solve this issue...
If anyone here who can help will be great. We have a solution for this instead of using metamask, we want to use wallet connect integration, but we dont know how to do that too. We have read the docs but we are too confuse in it....

Answer (score 0):

On mobile connecting to wallets will not work in your normal chrome/safari browsers- apple or other mobile creators do not allow this you can only connect your wallet by using the browser in your metamask app on your phone.
ie.

1. navigate to metamask or whichever wallet you are using on your phone
2. open the browser in that app
3. go to the website you need

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way with deeplinking to work with Android and IOS from the browser, it solved my problem with opening MetaMask and redirect my app there ( or installing if its not installed )

It's the complete code, you can find this part of code here :

https://github.com/EhsanParsania/MetaMask-React-sample/blob/main/src/components/MetaMaskInstallModal.js#L74

or clone it and run to use and check all features :

https://github.com/EhsanParsania/MetaMask-React-sample

and this is the specific code :

```html
function connectToPhoneMetamsk() {
const metamaskAppDeepLink = "https://metamask.app.link/dapp/" + YOUR_ORIGIN ; // put your origin here without http:// ro https://
return (
<a href={metamaskAppDeepLink}>
  <Button>Connect to MetaMask</Button>
</a>
);
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32526078)

Comment: I added the specific part of the code.